# Lambda / should change asymmetry in RSpec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Why does

```
            lambda {
            parse
            }.should change(Object.all, :length).by_at_least(1)
```

not work, while

```
        obj_count_before=Object.all.length
        parse
        Object.all.length.should >= obj_count_before +1
```

does?

Comment: what if you do: `lambda {parse}.should change(Object, :count).by_at_least(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this instead ([expect-change](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/expect-change))

```
expect { parse }.to change{Object.count}.by_at_least(1)
```